# Disable hyperlinks in minitoc while the hyperlinks are enabled in ToC

Tags: hyperref, minitoc

Is it possible to have hyperlinked entries in the ToC, while hyperlink is disabled in minitoc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Load the `minitoc` package before `hyperref`.  Immediately after loading `minitoc` save the definition of `\contentsline`, the macro that prints the entries, in another macro.  Via the command `\beforeminitoc`, restore the definition of `\contentsline` from the stored value.  The small catch is that in the meantime, `hyperref` has changed the number of arguments required by `\contentsline` from `3` to `4`, so you have to take that in to account in the code.

Table of contents:

[image: Sample toc]

Chapter:

[image: Sample chapter]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\let\stdcontentsline\contentsline
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\beforeminitoc}{\renewcommand{\contentsline}[4]{\stdcontentsline{##1}{##2}{##3}}}

\begin{document}

\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
\minitoc

\section{First section}

\section{Second section}

\end{document}
```