# Hyperlink only Section Number in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm trying to get my table of contents to hyperlink only the section numbering and the page number, like this:

[image: Table of contents example]

But I've only managed to get the page number to link with

```
 linktocpage = true
```

can anyone help with getting the section numbering (but not the titles) hyperlinked as well? Thanks.

Comment: Part of the solution is given by http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145601/disable-hyperlinks-in-minitoc-while-the-hyperlinks-are-enabled-in-toc

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't figure out how to treat sections different than chapters, even though argument #1 contains either "chapter" or "section" (or 
"part" or ...).  String compares just weren't working.  Let me know if you want the page numbers to be linked as well.

```
\documentclass{book}

\let\stdnumberline\numberline
\let\stdcontentsline\contentsline
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\contentsline}[4]%
{\bgroup
  \edef\anchorname{#4}
  \def\numberline#1{\stdnumberline{\hyperlink{\anchorname}{#1}}}
  \stdcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}
\egroup}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}

\section{First section}

\section{Second section}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks, colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue,linktoc=page]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\numberline#1{%
 \ifx\Hy@tocdestname\ltx@empty
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1\hfil}%
 \else
 \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}#1\hyper@linkend\hfil}%
 \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First}
\lipsum[66]

\subsection{First first}
\lipsum[66]

\section{Second}
\lipsum[66]

\subsection{Second second}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up hyperref:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linktoc = all}
```

Formulate every \section, \subsection, etc. to be included in the TOC as

```
\section[\textcolor{black}{NAME}]{NAME}
```

To color your text this way you will need

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

The text in the TOC will be visually indistinguishable from ordinary text, but will remain part of the link i.e. clickable. This is an utterly ridiculous hack as the option *should be*, but is not included in hyperref e.g.

```
\hypersetup{linktoc = numpage}
```

Dots (if included in the TOC) aren't part of the link in any case, with no obvious customization available. Hyperref has room for improvement.